# Mongoid and Full_text search issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, full-text-search, mongoid

I have been working on rails project, which had been made using noSql(Mongoid). Every thing is running fine.The issue is I want to add.. full text search here also. I had been using this gems for this...

```
gem 'mongoid_fulltext'
```

and my model file looks like this..

```
class Keyword
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::FullTextSearch
  field :name, type:String
  #index :name, unique: true
  embeds_many :posts

  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_uniqueness_of :name

  fulltext_search_in :name, :index_name => 'name_index'
end
```

and in controller.

```
@keywords = Keyword.fulltext_search(params[:search], :index => 'name_index')
```

and then `@keywords` always returns an empty array always.

Thanks
Awieet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from what I'm assuming are formatting errors, the only mistake I can find is that you seem to be naming the index manually.

Maybe in your fulltext_search call you should use `:index_name => 'name_index'` instead of `:index => 'name_index'`.

I'd advise just not messing with the default name of the index though, and removing that argument entirely from the method call.

Also, were the records persisted before you added the `mongoid_fulltext` gem? If so you'll need to call the `update_ngram_index` method on the Class object (or each instance) to add them to the index.

Other than that, have you checked out the `mongoid_search` gem as an alternative to `mongoid_fulltext`?

https://github.com/mauriciozaffari/mongoid_search

I've tried both and find find that this one has a much cleaner implementation and interface. Then again, I only use fulltext search sparingly. You may be using fulltext search more than I, and I'm not sure what the differences are feature-wise, but worth a look.

Hope that helps.